# change the variable name inside a loop

Tags: c#

I had a marquetool for my winform Application I obtained it from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24587/Easy-to-Use-Marquee-Control-for-Windows-Form-with?fid=1138401&tid=2731296)

And I that control I can Add Textelement By using the below code

```
MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement textElement1 = 
    new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement("TextElement 1");
MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement textElement2 = 
    new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement("TextElement 2");
MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement textElement3 = 
    new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement("TextElement 3");
superMarquee1.Elements.AddRange(new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement[] 
               {
                   textElement1,
                   textElement2,
                   textElement3
               }
```

but the issue is I had to fill the textelement from datatable , I did it like this

```
   for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count ;i++){
                String wholetext = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "--" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
            //    String textElement="textElement"+i.ToString();

                TextElement element = new TextElement(wholetext);

                MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement textElement1 = 
    new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement("wholetext");
            }
```

The 
issue is every time the same text textelemt is getting updated .
means It will be solved only when I can make different  identifier for the text element.
Can Anyone suggest how to change the varaibale name inside a loop

Comment: Maybe you should use an array or a <List> of Marquee-Elements and iterate through this list in your "update" code. Then you don't have to call them by their variable names but their indexes. 
Plus you have a compact handle for all the Marquee Elements, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's that you try to do but can you try this ?

```
List<TextElement> list = new List<TextElement>();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    String wholetext = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "--" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    list.Add(new TextElement(wholetext));
 }
 superMarquee1.Elements.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// creation
var marqueeList = new List<MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement>();

for (int i = 1; i<=3; i++)
{
  marqueeList.Add(new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement("TextElement "+i));
}

// usage
for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count ;i++)
{
  String wholetext = [here is your retrieving code];
  marqueeList[0] = new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement(wholetext); // 0 = first item
  // OR:
  marqueeList[i] = new MarqueControl.Entity.TextElement(wholetext);
}
```

Comment: it is working perfectly but I added one more line atlast superMarquee1.Elements.AddRange(marqueeList.ToArray());

Comment: Yes, of course - I forgot the line where you use your objects at last. :)